# Within lxc/docker container - what happens if apt-get upgrade includes kernel update?

Tags: linux, docker, lxc

I am reading a lot of Docker guides where the will often use some Ubuntu base image and in the Dockerfile directly or in a bash script that gets copy to container and run on start, it has things like 'apt-get upgrade'

As i understand it, the container still uses the hosts kernel. So what happens when the apt-get upgrade includes a kernel upgrade? Does it create a /boot and install the files as usual but the underlying LXC has some pass-through/whitelist mechanism for specific directories that always come from host... so it ignores those files in guest container ?

Thanks
fLo

Answer (score 1):

The host's `/boot` is not visible to a Docker container, and the kernel image package should not be installed in such a container, since it's not needed. (Even if it is, though, it's entirely inert.)

Comment: ok thanks, the fact all the guides i read usually use debbootstrap to make a fresh base image and then make no attempt at excluding kernel updates during package management for example is what confused me. I guess even though the update might install a new kernel image into the containers /boot directory, it makes no difference.

Comment: `debootstrap` doesn't install a kernel at all by default. That's normally handled by d-i.